# ggplot2 tile plots with horizontal panels of different heights

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

This is basically the same question [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638294/geom-tile-and-facet-grid-facet-wrap-for-same-height-of-tiles), but with one important difference: I want a ggplot2-based tile plot with *horizontal* panels, and where all of the tiles are of equal height. The other question was about vertical panels.

Here’s some example code, based on the one in the other question:

```
d = data.frame(sites=rep(paste("S", 1:31),each=12),
               month=factor(rep(1:12,31)),
               value=runif(31*12),
               panel=c(rep("Group 1",16*12), rep("Group 2", 12*12),
                       rep("Group 3", 3*12)))
```

Plotting this using

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=month, y=sites, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="white") + facet_wrap(~panel, nrow=1)
```

results in [image]

Basically, I want each block of blue tiles moved up, so that there is no space above them. I can achieve this using

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=month, y=sites, fill=value, colour="white")) + 
  geom_tile(colour="white") + facet_wrap(~panel, scales="free_y", nrow=1)
```

but this results in tiles of unequal height:

[image]

[The other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638294/geom-tile-and-facet-grid-facet-wrap-for-same-height-of-tiles) had a nice solution for vertical panels, but applying this to the above code has no effect. Is there a similar solution for horizontal panels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a hack using `gridExtra` and setting up levels:

```
d.splt <- split(d, d$panel)
max.unique <- max(sapply(d.splt, function(x) length(unique(x$sites))))
d.gg <- lapply(d.splt, function(d.sub){
  lvls <- unique(as.character(d.sub$sites))
  length(lvls) <- max.unique
  lvls <- replace(lvls, is.na(lvls), "")
  d.sub$sites <- factor(as.character(d.sub$sites), levels=lvls)

  ggplot(d.sub, aes(x=month, y=sites, fill=value, colour="white")) + 
    geom_tile(colour="white", stat="identity") +
    scale_y_discrete(drop=F) + scale_fill_continuous(guide=F)
} )
library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(d.gg, list(nrow=1)))
```

[image]

This will throw some warnings, but you can ignore them.  Also, you'll need to add titles and also a legend (you can mess with the logic so the last one produces a legend).

The main issue with this is that the color scale will be fit for each graph independently, but there you can force that to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for a nice solution. And it’s easy enough to change to move the blocks to the top instead of the bottom. One thing I would change, though, is `lvls <- unique(as.character(d.sub$sites))` to `lvls <- levels(droplevels(d.sub$sites))`, to keep the order of the rows (it doesn’t matter for my example data, since the rows were already labelled/ordered numerically), but for other data, it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll accept @BrodieG’s solution, since that is the most general solution to my question, but I’ll add my own, for the special case where the actual row/site names don’t matter, only the (within-panel) order of the tile rows. Here we can use a hack where we change the level names in all the subgroups to the ones used in the group with the largest number of rows. Example data and original plot:

```
# Example data
set.seed(7)
d = data.frame(sites=rep(paste("S", 1:31),each=12),
               month=factor(rep(1:12,31)),
               value=runif(31*12),
               panel=c(rep("Group 1",16*12),
                       rep("Group 2", 12*12),
                       rep("Group 3", 3*12)))

# Reorder rows / site names (just to show that the code works properly)
d$sites = reorder(d$sites, d$value, mean)

# Original plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=month, y=sites, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="white") + facet_wrap(~panel, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Now we only need to change the site names of each subgroup:

```
# Fetch the name of the group with the most rows
library(plyr)
d.stat = ddply(d, .(panel), summarise, nrows=length(unique(sites)))
maxpanel = with(d.stat, panel[which.max(nrows)])

# Fetch the levels / rownames of the group with the most rows
levels.maxpanel = levels(droplevels(subset(d, panel==maxpanel))$sites)

# Substitute the levels / row names of the
# biggest group for each subgroup
subs.levels = function(d.sub) {
  levels.subpanel = rev(levels(droplevels(d.sub$sites)))
  d.sub$sites[] = rev(levels.maxpanel)[match(d.sub$sites, levels.subpanel)]
  d.sub
}
d.recoded = ddply(d, .(panel), subs.levels)

# New plot
ggplot(d.recoded, aes(x=month, y=sites, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="white") + facet_wrap(~panel, nrow=1) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

[image]