# set ggplot plots to have same x-axis width and same space between dot plot rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

**Updated question to incorporate a partial solution already answered on SO**

I am using `ggplot2` to create several plots and `gridExtra` to combine the plots into one figure with several panels, all in one column. My problem is that I can't get the space between the dot plot rows to be consistent in both plots.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
# data
  dat1 <- data.frame(VARIABLES=c("Item 1", "Item 2 is a little longer"),
                     est=c(.3, .5),
                     min=c(.2, .4),
                     max=c(.4, .7))
  dat2 <- data.frame(VARIABLES=c("Item 3", 
                                 "Item 4 is even longer if you can believe it",
                                 "And there is a third item",
                                 "And a fourth item"),
                     est=c(.3, .5, .3, .5),
                     min=c(.2, .4, .2, .4),
                     max=c(.4, .7, .4, .7))
  dat <- c("dat1", "dat2")
  labs <- c("Plot 1", "Plot2")
# create plots
  count <- 1
  for (i in dat) {
    p <- ggplot(get(i), aes(x=reorder(as.character(VARIABLES), est), 
                              y=est)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=min,
                        ymax=max),
                    linetype="dashed") +
    geom_point(size=3) +
    ylim(-1,1) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title = labs[count]) +
    theme(legend.position="none") +
    coord_flip()
    assign(paste(i, "plot", sep="."), p)
    count <- count+1
  }
# combine plots
  library(gridExtra)
  # approach suggested by @baptise
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot
  gA <- ggplotGrob(dat1.plot)
  gB <- ggplotGrob(dat2.plot)
  maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:5], gB$widths[2:5])
  gA$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
  gB$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
  grid.arrange(gA, gB, ncol=1)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `facets` instead of `grid.arrange`, but "ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip."

Comment: @shadow, yes, I was disappointed to learn this. I originally thought facets might be the answer.

Comment: I think #1 is mostly a variation of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638294/geom-tile-and-facet-grid-facet-wrap-for-same-height-of-tiles/20639481#20639481)

Comment: @baptiste, what is appropriate in this case since (1) has been answered in another question, but not (2)? Should I edit the question to incorporate the other answer for (1) and clarify that my question deals with (2)?

Comment: I have no idea. My guess is that it's best to have only one specific problem per question in the first place. Go ahead an edit, I've removed my closing vote.

Comment: I got the 'answer' in the question above to work for me when I used `gA$widths[2:5] <- maxWidth` instead of `gA$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)`, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

gb1 <- ggplot_build(dat1.plot)
gb2 <- ggplot_build(dat2.plot)

# work out how many y breaks for each plot
n1 <- length(gb1$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.labels)
n2 <- length(gb2$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.labels)

gA <- ggplot_gtable(gb1)
gB <- ggplot_gtable(gb2)

g <- rbind(gA, gB)

# locate the panels in the gtable layout
panels <- g$layout$t[grepl("panel", g$layout$name)]
# assign new (relative) heights to the panels, based on the number of breaks
g$heights[panels] <- unit(c(n1,n2),"null")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: this looks like it will work. thanks. however, i get to `g <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(gA, gB, gC, gD, gE, "last")` in my actual code (note i'm adding 3 more plots) and i get an error about unused arguments. i looked at the `rbind.gtable` documentation, but nothing jumped out at me. any guesses as to what is causing the error?

Comment: also, @baptiste, is it possible to modify the code to specify a specific space between rows? your code seems to answer the question perfectly. just wondering if it is possible to specify a particular spacing that could be applied to all plots.

Comment: I've updated [my original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13295880/471093) to cater for multiple plots. Space between plots is defined by the plot margins; alternatively you could look at `?gtable_add_rows` and similar functions in the gtable docs.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it gets the job done. Thanks! Your other code works great for multiple plots, though I was unsure how to modify to include the height adjustment you include in the current answer. A note for other folks coming to this thread: long labels get cutoff.

Comment: I was able to get the code in the answer working perfectly for multiple plots by adding parameters for my additional 3 plots: `gb3...gb5, n3...n5, gC...gE` and `g1 <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(gA, gB, "last")`, `g2 <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(g1, gC, "last")`,...`g <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(g3, gE, "last")`. I also had to update with `unit(n3,"null")...unit(n5,"null")`. Finally setting the output size with `cairo_pdf(f, width=7, height=9) and wrapping this around ` grid.draw(g)` with `dev.off()` produced a great looking figure. Thanks, @baptiste.

Comment: @EricGreen Do you have the code for multiple plots?

Comment: @baptiste any chance you could update this for the latest gridExtra? having trouble getting this to work based on https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/arranging-ggplot

Comment: I don't know, but I think today the following syntax has changed:
n1 <- length(gb1$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.labels) to
n1 <- length(gb1$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.labels)

Comment: Instead of using  g <- rbind(gA, gB), it should be used g <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(gA, gB, "last")

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach: fill in extra spaces for shorter labels and use a monospace font.

```
longest_name <- max(nchar(as.character(dat1$VARIABLES)), nchar(as.character(dat2$VARIABLES)))
fill_in_spaces <- function(v) paste0(paste0(rep(" ", longest_name - nchar(v)), collapse=""), v)
levels(dat1$VARIABLES) <- sapply(levels(dat1$VARIABLES), fill_in_spaces)
levels(dat2$VARIABLES) <- sapply(levels(dat2$VARIABLES), fill_in_spaces)
```

Then the plotting procedure is almost the same, just add

```
p <- p + theme(text=element_text(family="Courier", size=14))
```

[image]

There is a minor issue: levels are reordered, so Item 3 is now the last, but that can be easily fixed like described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744178/ggplot2-sorting-a-plot).

Comment: interesting approach for problem #2, @tonytonov

Comment: @EricGreen Thanks, it was a completely random idea and it (surprisingly) worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat1$Plot <- "Plot 1"
dat2$Plot <- "Plot 2"
dataset <- rbind(dat1, dat2)

ggplot(
  dataset, 
  aes(
    y = reorder(as.character(VARIABLES), est), 
    x = est,
    xmin = min,
    xmax = max
  )) +
  geom_errorbarh() + geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~Plot, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: `facet_grid(Plot~., scales = "free", space="free")` would solve #1