# ggplot2: Using gtable to move strip labels to top of panel for facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, gtable

I am creating a graphic using `facet_grid` to facet a categorical variable on the y-axis. I decided not to use `facet_wrap` because I need `space = 'free'` and `labeller = label_parsed`. My labels are long and I have a legend on the right so I would like to move the labels from  the right of the panel to the top of the panel.

Here is an example to show where I'm getting stuck.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

mt <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = model)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = 'free', space = 'free') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.margin = unit(0.5, 'lines'), strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image: mt.png]

Now I would like to move the strip text from the right of each panel to the top of each panel. I can store the grobs for the strip labels and remove them from the plot:

```
grob <- ggplotGrob(mt)
strips.y <- gtable_filter(grob, 'strip-right')
grob2 <- grob[,-5]
```

But now I'm stuck when it comes to `rbind`-ing the grobs back so the labels go to the top of the panels.

Another possible solution would be to use `facet_wrap` and then re-size the panels [as discussed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099801/3017012), but in that case I would have to manually change the labels on the facets because there is no `labeller = label_parsed` for `facet_wrap`.

I'd appreciate suggestions on either approach!

Thanks for reading,

Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This takes your first approach. It inserts a row above each of the panels, grabs the strip grobs (on the right), and inserts them into the new rows.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

mt <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = model)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = 'free', space = 'free') +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0.5, 'lines'), 
         strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))

# Get the gtable
gt <- ggplotGrob(mt)

# Get the position of the panels in the layout
panels <-c(subset(gt$layout, grepl("panel", gt$layout$name), se=t:r))

# Add a row above each panel
for(i in rev(panels$t-1)) gt = gtable_add_rows(gt, unit(.5, "lines"), i)

# Get the positions of the panels and the strips in the revised layout
panels <-c(subset(gt$layout, grepl("panel", gt$layout$name), se=t:r))
strips <- c(subset(gt$layout, grepl("strip-r", gt$layout$name), se=t:r))

# Get the strip grobs
stripText = gtable_filter(gt, "strip-r")

# Insert the strip grobs into the new rows
for(i in 1:length(strips$t)) gt = gtable_add_grob(gt, stripText$grobs[[i]]$grobs[[1]],  t=panels$t[i]-1, l=4)

# Remove the old strips
gt = gt[,-5]

# For this plot - adjust the heights of the strips and the empty row above the strips
for(i in panels$t) {
   gt$heights[i-1] = unit(0.8, "lines")
   gt$heights[i-2] = unit(0.2, "lines")
   }

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

OR, you can achieve the second approach using a `facet_wrap_labeller` function [available from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979017/changing-facet-label-to-math-formula-in-ggplot2).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

mt <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = model)) + geom_point() +
   facet_wrap(~ manufacturer, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) +
   theme(panel.margin = unit(0.2, 'lines'))


facet_wrap_labeller <- function(gg.plot, labels=NULL) {
  require(gridExtra)

  g <- ggplotGrob(gg.plot)
  gg <- g$grobs      
  strips <- grep("strip_t", names(gg))

  for(ii in seq_along(labels))  {
    modgrob <- getGrob(gg[[strips[ii]]], "strip.text", 
                       grep=TRUE, global=TRUE)
    gg[[strips[ii]]]$children[[modgrob$name]] <- editGrob(modgrob,label=labels[ii])
  }

  g$grobs <- gg
  class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g)) 
  return(g)
}

## Number of y breaks in each panel
g <- ggplot_build(mt) 
N <- sapply(lapply(g$panel$ranges, "[[", "y.major"), length)

# Some arbitrary strip texts
StripTexts = expression(gamma[1], sqrt(gamma[2]), C, `A really incredibly very very very long label`, gamma[5], alpha[1], alpha[2], `Land Rover`, alpha[1], beta[2], gamma^2, delta^2, epsilon[2], zeta[3], eta[4] )

 # Apply the facet_wrap_labeller function
gt = facet_wrap_labeller(mt, StripTexts)

# Get the position of the panels in the layout
panels <- gt$layout$t[grepl("panel", gt$layout$name)]

# Replace the default panel heights with relative heights
gt$heights[panels] <- lapply(N, unit, "null")

# Draw it
gt
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I just made a couple of small changes to your first approach so that I could make it into a function:

`for(i in 1:length(strips$t)) gt = gtable_add_grob(gt, stripText$grobs[[i]],  t=panels$t[i]-1, l=4, r=4)` 
-> 
`for(i in 1:length(strips$t)) gt = gtable_add_grob(gt, stripText$grobs[[i]],  t = panels$t[i]-1, l = min(panels$l), r = max(panels$r))` 
to insert the new strip grobs and 
`gt = gt[,-5]` 
-> 
`gt <- gt[,-c(min(strips$l), max(strips$r))]` 
to remove the old strips.

Comment: Update for this that works with current ggplot2? Strips are labelled differently etc. I couldn't make this work.

Comment: @JanStanstrup First version edited and works as expected - for now. Be patient - second version coming.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with a similar problem but putting the labels on the bottom. I've used a code adaptation of this answer. And recently found that

ggplot2 ver.2.2.1.0 (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html)

`~facet_grid(.~variable,switch='x')`

option which has worked beautifully for me.